# lemon install SOPLEX, COIN and ILOG libraries

Tags: c++, lemon-graph-library

I was trying to install Lemon on Ubuntu 14.04. I was going as per the instructions in their documentation. On the "cmake .." command, I got an error as the following

```
aniket@aniket-Lenovo-G50-45:~/lemon-1.3.1/build$ cmake ..
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (CMAKE_POLICY):
Policy "CMP0048" is not known to this version of CMake.

-- Could NOT find ILOG (missing:  ILOG_CPLEX_LIBRARY ILOG_CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find COIN (missing:  COIN_INCLUDE_DIR COIN_CBC_LIBRARY COIN_CBC_SOLVER_LIBRARY COIN_CGL_LIBRARY COIN_CLP_LIBRARY COIN_COIN_UTILS_LIBRARY COIN_OSI_LIBRARY COIN_OSI_CBC_LIBRARY COIN_OSI_CLP_LIBRARY) 
-- Could NOT find SOPLEX (missing:  SOPLEX_LIBRARY SOPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/aniket/lemon-1.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/aniket/lemon-1.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I tried to update and upgrade Cmake just in case. But, it didn't help. So, is this about the libraries not being installed (COIN, ILOG, etc)? How do I install them?

Answer (score 0):

No, I've just succeeded in installation by commenting third line in CMakeLists.txt:

```
#CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0048 OLD)
```

So, the problem is not in COIN, ILOG, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a library problem, rather than a `CMAKE_POLICY` problem. I was having the same issue, as my `cmake` was not recognizing the following policy:

```
CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0048 OLD)
```

Turned out that my `cmake` version (2.8.xx) was too old. After upgrading to `cmake` 3.0.2, this issue was fixed.