# installation lemon Could NOT find ILOG COIN SOPLEX

Tags: unix, github, installation, lemon-graph-library

I am trying to install a [github repository](https://github.com/oscarhiggott/PyMatching/) and on running as follows

```
/home/user/.local/bin/python3 -m pip install -e /home/user/repository_folder_name
```

I get the following error

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/user/.local/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/user/PyMatching/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/user/PyMatching/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
     cwd: /home/user/PyMatching/
Complete output (54 lines):
running develop
running egg_info
writing src/PyMatching.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src/PyMatching.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to src/PyMatching.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to src/PyMatching.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src/PyMatching.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'src/PyMatching.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
-- pybind11 v2.4.dev4
CMake Warning (dev) at lib/lemon/CMakeLists.txt:6 (PROJECT):
  Policy CMP0048 is not set: project() command manages VERSION variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0048" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The following variable(s) would be set to empty:

    LEMON_VERSION
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find ILOG (missing: ILOG_CPLEX_LIBRARY ILOG_CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find COIN (missing: COIN_CBC_LIBRARY COIN_CBC_SOLVER_LIBRARY COIN_CGL_LIBRARY COIN_CLP_LIBRARY COIN_OSI_LIBRARY COIN_OSI_CBC_LIBRARY COIN_OSI_CLP_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find SOPLEX (missing: SOPLEX_LIBRARY SOPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/PyMatching
Error: could not load cache
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090258/lemon-install-soplex-coin-and-ilog-libraries). But I have tried commenting out #CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0048 OLD)
and made sure that I am using the latest version of cmake.

I have no idea how to find these development libraries or find alternatives. Please suggest how to resolve this. Also, this is an issue only on the unix server where I am trying to run this. On my local Windows computer, installation went smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of PyMatching and I've now added it to the Python package index (see [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyMatching/)) so you can install the latest version from PyPI with pip:

```
pip install pymatching
```

Since pip will fetch the wheels, which have been built for various platforms, this should hopefully fix your issue, as you won't need to build it yourself.

If you still need to build your own local copy of the PyMatching source code for some reason, just cloning the latest version of the [repo](https://github.com/oscarhiggott/PyMatching) might also solve your problem, as I've switched to a more recent version of the Lemon C++ library since you posted.

If this doesn't fix the problem, you could also create an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/oscarhiggott/PyMatching) and/or let me know which version of your operating system you're using.